# Best way to continuously replicate (single direction) table when documents within are created continuously per second

Tags: couchdb

If I'm trying to continuously replicate (single direction) a table (i.e. system logs) that has multiple documents added to it per second in a never ending cycle, what is the best way to do this? I'm seeing that the job just hangs. I believe the system is waiting for the table to have a moment when nothing is being changed in order to initiate the replication which will never happen to this table.

I just left my standup and explained this issue with the team and they said not to replicate this particular table because it's not replicating. But I'd still like to understand if there's a solution out there.

Comment: CouchDB doesn't sound like the right tool for this. I'd encourage using a proper tool/format, such as syslog. CouchDB has entirely different goals than what you typically want for logging. CouchDB has certain guarantees about data consistency. Usually with logging, you'd rather lose a few logs, than to get backed up. CouchDB will create a huge backlog of data, rather than lose data. Further, with CouchDB, your documents are never deleted. The tombstone docs will quickly fill your hard drive in your scenario.

Comment: @Flimzy I agree with you 100% as Couch not being the right tool for capturing logs. Unfortunately I am inheriting this project as well as the low person on the totem pole which means I have no voice in this. But I will pass along the fact about memory consumption that you mention. Even though we are no longer replicating this table, it is still having thousands of documents added per hour.